# Show that running time of Quick Sort is $\mathcal O(n^2)$ when array contains distinct elements and is sorted in descending order

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms, sorting

I'm trying to study running time for various algorithms. Now I have QuickSort. How exactly is the running time of an algorithm calculated, I know how quick sort works and the Asymptontic notations. I understand that $\Theta$ Notation bounds functions above and below, Big-O above and $\Omega$ provides a lower bound.
How exactly is this running time calculated ? Can some one explain this for a noob please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $n$ a *representative size* in your program. Let's say $n$ is the length of the list you're working with.

The runnig time, or **complexity**, of an algorithm is the number of operations you need to do so that your algorithm terminates with an entry data of size $n$.

You also have to choose which operations you count, only multiplications, every arithmetic operation, comparsions...
The expression of complexity $\mathcal C(n)$ is generally obtained by a recursive process.

Let $p(n)$ be $n, n^3, 2^n,$ or $n\log(n)$ for example

To indicate complexity we use $3$ functions, because $\mathcal C(n)$ is not very relevant :
$$\Omega(p(n)) : p(n) <_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathcal C(n)$$
$$\mathcal O(p(n)) : p(n) >_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathcal C(n)$$
$$\Theta(p(n)) : p(n) \sim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathcal C(n) $$

Comment: Thanks but this is confusing.Can you explain to me in a lower level.What does it mean by "algorithm terminates with an entry data of size n" ? what is this entry.I did not understand anything below this :)

Comment: The execution time has generally a direct link with the size of the data it has to deal with. I mean, here you enter a list to sort : it will take more time if your list contains $150000$ elements ($n=150000$) than if it only has $10$ ($n=10$). We don't calculate actually a running *time*, but rather a number of operations needed to get the result

Comment: okay............ what is p(n) ?

Comment: I noted $p(n)$, but you never use it in a concrete exercise. It is just a simple expression depending of $n$ that you will put in the $\mathcal O$, or the $\Theta$, or the $\Omega$. For instance, if you find $\mathcal C(n) = 2n^2-\frac{n}{5}+6\sqrt{n}$, you will say that $\mathcal C(n) = \Theta(n^2)$, because when $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\mathcal C(n) \sim n^2$

Comment: For insertion sort the worst case running time is given by an² +bn+c .So we can represent running time by O(n² ) . ie: we ignore the terms with low coefficient.

Comment: Exact. It gives a more efficient idea of the algorithm's complexity : when $n$ is very large, only the terms with the biggest coefficients matter

Comment: But how do we know which asymptotic notation to use ?

Comment: It depends on what you want to express : "My algorithm will need at least/at max that number of operations to give a result". $\mathcal O$ is fine, the two others are more used for more complex complexity calculations

Comment: But O only gives asymptotic upper bound right? Like we use it when we say my alg needs maximum of n steps right? I use theta to say my algorithm will have minimum this much steps and maximum this much.Does it work like that?

Comment: Yes. It's just that for many algorithms, no one cares of the minimum number of steps required. Therefore the use of $\mathcal O$ is more common

Comment: If this has been helpful to you, please remember to upvote and accept the answer :)

Comment: I did.Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

In each partition, the pivot element is always the smallest element. therefore each partition will produce two subarrays. the first subarray contains only one element(the smallest element) and this element is in its correct position. the second subarray contains the remaining elements.
so the running time recurrence will be T(n) = T(n-1) + n. thus T(n) = Ө(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

If the array is already sorted in decreasing order, then, the pivot element is less than all the other elements. The partition step takes Θ(n) time, and then leaves you with a subproblem of size n − 1 and a subproblem of size 0. This gives us the recurrence T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(0) + Θ(n).
Note that: T(0) = Θ(1).
So, in each level we will have n decreased by 1 and the partitioning cost is still Θ(n), that leaves us with T(n - 1) = T(n - 2) + T(0) + Θ(n) again.

Simply, we will have around n levels and on each level has a processing that costs Θ(n) time. That leads to Θ(n^2) time.